# Confidence interval when data is in range

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate the confidence interval when data is given in range.

Example:

Rather than telling their exact age in years, 9 sample students from a class tell their age as:

> (23 +/-1)  ;   (22 +/-1) ;  (20 +/-2 ) ; (25 +/-2) ;  (24 +/-2) ;  (25 +/-3) ;  (22 +/-3) ; (24 +/-4) ; (25 +/- 4 )

How do we calculate XY% confidence interval in such scenario.

Comment: It depends on what the underlying age distribution is and how they go about deciding which age to report (If I am 22 and a bit, I might say "21", "22" or "23"... but perhaps young people prefer to round up (on the other hand, perhaps, old people prefer to round down).

Comment: Yeah, we dont have information about age distribution. We believe that although a student is not giving his age in concrete numbers, he is telling 100% truth. Can we model the age distribution for (23 +/- 1) by considering 22,23,24 as datapoints?

Comment: Given you're not getting the actual age, I'm not sure what "he is telling 100% truth" means. If you see "23", what's the probability that it was really 22, that it was really 23, that it was really 24? (and on what basis do you arrive at those probabilities?)